# Defining isJavaIdentifierStart method

Tags: java, methods, char, boolean

In Java’s Character class, there’s a method named isJavaIdentifierStart(char ch). This method determines if the char argument is permissible as the first character in a Java identifier. A character may start a Java identifier if and only if it is (1) a letter; (2) a currency symbol (i.e., ‘$’); or (3) a connecting punctuation character (i.e., ‘_’ which is the underscore). This method returns true if the character may start a Java identifier; false otherwise.

How do I go about defining my own isJavaIdentifierStart method? So far I have:

```
public class MyCharacter {

  public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char c) {
     return true;
  }

}

//('a') == true);
//('7') == false);
//('_') == true);
//('$') == true);
//('Z') == true);
//('.') == false);
```

Comment: Do you know about `if` statements? That will be your best starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are beginning  to do it with `switch/case/default` this way:

```
   public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char c) {
         switch (c) {
         case 'a' : return true;
         //Fill other cases
         default: return false; //default is false
      }        
    }
```

You can also try some if else blocks:

```
   public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char c) {
         if(c=='a'){
             return true;
         }else if(c=='_'){
             return true;
         }else if (){//Fill other cases
         }else return false; //default is false
      }        
    }
```

Comment: Would it possible to replace switch with if statements? Cheers

Comment: Of course. You can try it in few ways. if is more flexible, since it you can use different conditions. If you going to use if's, you can also use regular expressions, as was already suggested among answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```java
return String.valueOf(c).matches("[a-z$_]");
```

Add other allowed chars you may need between the character class:

```
[a-z$£€_.-]
```

Just be aware the dash character `-` must be put either at the beginning `[-...]` or at the end `[...-]` of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`switch - case`** to implement, like

```
public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char c) {

    switch(c)
    {
    case 'a':
    case '_':
    case '$':
    case 'Z': return true;

    case '7':
    case '.': return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use a Set of allowed characters, and to check if the Set contains the given char:

```java
private static final Set<Character> ALLOWED_JAVA_IDENTIFIER_STARTS;

static {
    Set<Character> allowedJavaIdentifierStarts = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        allowedJavaIdentifierStarts.add(c);
    }
    allowedJavaIdentifierStarts.addAll(Arrays.asList('$', '£', 'z'));
    allowedJavaIdentifierStarts.addAll(Arrays.asList('.', '-', '_'));
    ALLOWED_JAVA_IDENTIFIER_STARTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(allowedJavaIdentifierStarts);
}

public static boolean isJavaIdentifierStart(char c) {
    return ALLOWED_JAVA_IDENTIFIER_STARTS.contains(c);
}
```